# Is there a cut-off function $\theta$ so that, if $\nabla \cdot \varphi = 0$, then $\nabla \cdot (\theta\varphi) = 0$

Tags: analysis, divergence-operator

Let us consider the channels $A = \mathbb R \times[-1, 1]$, $B = \mathbb R \times[-2, 2]$ and a smooth function $\boldsymbol{\varphi}: \Omega \subset \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$, for $\Omega$ an open set containing $A$ and $B$, which has a free divergence, $\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{\varphi} = 0$. I know that we can easily construct a $C^\infty$-function $\theta: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that
$$\theta(x, y) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } |y| \le 1,\\
0 & \text{if } |y| \ge 2.
\end{cases}$$
Now is it possible to construct such a $\theta$ but with the additional property $\theta \boldsymbol{\varphi}$ still has a free divergence, $\nabla \cdot (\theta\boldsymbol{\varphi}) = 0~?$ I have absolutely no clue how to start, any help ?

Comment: Doesn't divergence operate on vector-valud functions rather than scalar-valued functions like $\theta$? (Also what do $A$ and $B$ have to do with the question?)

Comment: @GregMartin Yes indeed sorry, I wrote my question a bit quickly.

Comment: In other words, such that $\boldsymbol\varphi\cdot\nabla\theta = 0$.

Comment: The usual way to cutoff $\phi$ while staying divergence-free  is somehow to conjugate with curl. namely, since $\phi$ is smooth and divergence-free, by Helmholtz decomposition $\phi=\nabla\times \Phi$ for some smooth $\Phi$. Then set $\tilde \phi := \nabla\times (\theta \Phi)$. Where $\theta=1$, $\tilde\phi=\phi$, where $\theta=0$, so is $\tilde \phi$, and it is clearly divergence-free. This isn't of the form you ask for, since it adds a correction $\nabla\theta\times \Phi$ to $\theta \phi$