# Cutoff a divergence-free function while staying divergence-free

Tags: functional-analysis, divergence-operator

This question is related to [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4449792/is-there-a-cut-off-function-theta-so-that-if-nabla-cdot-varphi-0-the) I've asked. Let us consider the two channels $A = \mathbb R \times[-1, 1]$, $B = \mathbb R \times[-2, 2]$ and the functions $\boldsymbol{\varphi}, \boldsymbol{\psi}: \Omega \subset \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2 \in C^\infty(\Omega) \cap L^2(\Omega)$ , for $\Omega$ an open set containing $A$ and $B$, which have free divergence. Assume that $\text{supp }\boldsymbol{\varphi}\subset A$ and that
$$\|\boldsymbol{\varphi} - \boldsymbol{\psi}\|_{L^2(\Omega)} < \varepsilon.$$
I would like to show that, in this case there exists a divergence free $\boldsymbol{\tilde{\psi}} \in C^\infty(\Omega) \cap L^2(\Omega)$, equal to $\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol \psi}$ on $A$, such that $\text{supp }\boldsymbol{\tilde\psi}\subset B$ and
$$\|\boldsymbol{\varphi} - \boldsymbol{\tilde\psi}\|_{L^2(\Omega)} < \varepsilon.$$
As suggested by @Calvin Khor in the comment of the previous question, I could define a cutoff function
$$
\theta = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{in } A,\\
0 & \text{in } B^c.
\end{cases}
$$
As $\boldsymbol{\psi}$ has a free divergence, there exists a smooth scalar function $\zeta$ such that $\boldsymbol{\psi} = \nabla \times (0,0,\zeta)$. If we set $\boldsymbol{\tilde\psi} = \nabla \times (0,0,\theta\zeta) = \zeta\nabla \theta + \theta \boldsymbol{\psi}$ we have
\begin{align}
\|\boldsymbol{\varphi} - \boldsymbol{\tilde\psi}\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 &= \|\boldsymbol{\varphi} - \boldsymbol{\psi}\|_{L^2(A)}^2 + \|\boldsymbol{\tilde\psi}\|^2_{L^2(B \backslash A)}\\
&= \|\boldsymbol{\varphi} - \boldsymbol{\psi}\|_{L^2(A)}^2 + \|\zeta\nabla \theta + \theta \boldsymbol{\psi}\|^2_{L^2(B \backslash A)}
\end{align}
Is there a way from here to show that $\|\zeta\nabla \theta + \theta \boldsymbol{\psi}\|^2_{L^2(B \backslash A)}$ must be lower than $\varepsilon~?$ I really don't see how to control this term..

Comment: Maybe a dumb question: in your second formula, right hand side, do you really need the same $\varepsilon$ as in the first? Would it be ok to have $C\varepsilon$ for some fixed $C>0$ instead?

Comment: Anyways, you know that $\psi$ is small in $B\setminus A$ as it is close to $\phi$, so you can control $\theta \psi$ in the $L^2$ norm. Then you only need to bound $\zeta$ in that same region... Honestly I don't see how at the moment, I was trying to see whether some Fourier analysis could help

Comment: I don't see any reason why $\zeta$ has to be in $L^2$ in the first place... The potential $\zeta$ is not even guaranteed to have support in $\Omega$ in the first place, since it is obtained as a convolution between $\psi$ and a kernel of degree $-1$. I could be wrong since $\zeta$ is not uniquely determined, but this suggests me there is probably some modification that is needed